# How to raise one DialogFragment above another?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Say I have several dialog fragments that are shown in response to messages and events that can arrive in any order.  Normally, the last dialog shown will be on top.  **Is there a way to show a dialog fragment *under* an existing one, or change their z-order after they are shown?**

It should be pretty rare for my app to show more than one dialog at a time, but it could happen.  There is one particular dialog that should always be on top whenever it's visible.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Those downvotes do not make sense at all. +1'ed to counterbalance. Plus, I'm investigating on this question, it is definitely an interesting one.

Comment: Why would you want multiple dialogs shown? I'd recommend a different approach as clicking 'dismiss' on a bunch of dialogs would be a pretty awful experience. Consider a different approach, such as a dialog manager that maintains display priority of dialogs as they appear.

Comment: @Cookster How does your suggestion differ, and how would I implement it?

Comment: Create a Dialog Fragment Manager that can check if any dialog is visible. When you call "showDialog( dialog_id )", have it automatically evaluate if the new dialog_id has priority over the existing dialog. If it does, dismiss current and show new dialog. If it doesn't, drop the event. Alternatively, depending on implementation, you can update the existing dialog with additional information if the priority is of equal importance.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede how many dialogue fragment you want to show at a time ?

Comment: @PreethiRao Normally just one, but it would be possible for there to be more than one.  For example, a Bluetooth connectivity problem could occur at the same time as a job offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dialog creates an application sub-window. Android's window manager ([WindowManagerService](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java)) automatically computes window's z-order depending on its type and stores it in [WindowState](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowState.java)'s `mLayer` field. Internal Android classes have access to this field and change window's z-order sometimes, but this API is not exposed to Android SDK. So it seems that the only way to affect dialog's z-order is to recreate it.

Everything I wrote above is just a result of a brief investigation of Android's source code so I may be wrong. And maybe there's some hacky way to do what you want using reflection and accessing private fields and methods. But I'm not sure it's a good idea to try and do it. In my opinion it would be better to have just a single dialog or even activity, and manage fragments within it.

Comment: Can it be modified via Reflection?

Comment: @dextor, the window manager works in the Android runtime process so it cannot be accessed via reflection.