# How to place a DialogFragment above/below another DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I´m trying to show some content abov/below a Dialog fragment but I don´t want those 2 to be on the same XML layout because one of those DialogFragment is wider than the other and if they are on the same XML it looks just weird. So I´m trying to achieve something like this:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B80ZR.png)

I found this question here: [How to raise one DialogFragment above another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157809/how-to-raise-one-dialogfragment-above-another) but I don´t think that applies to my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different dialogs aren't necessary here. Inflate only one dialog with two cards inside it.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView ... />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView ... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```